# Count the number of times data appears in a query

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am a relatively new user to Access and VBA and I'm looking for some help with some data I would like to assemble and I'm trying to figure out the best way. I have a database that tracks my employees performance checks. they are checked on 10 accounts per month and I would like to a see a list of the employees that fail 3 or more checks in a given month. I have the query I've imaged below built so that it looks at all the checks for the month and calls only the ones that did not pass. What I would like is a list of just the people that appear on this query 3 or more times in the given month. Any help would be appreciated.

[Image of query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcUxC.jpg)

Comment: select q.person from (your query goes here) as q group by q.person having count (*) >= 3

Comment: So what would the code look like for your solution? I presume it would go as an expression in the query builder?

Comment: i would use SQL view rather than query builder, so you can "nest" your existing query inside the above select statement with "group by" and "having" clauses. "person" refers to whatever your employee column is called in your existing query.

Comment: Thank you for the fast responses! I have the table "tblQA" which contains the "Pass" field and the "UserLogin" field (see image in OP) the code I am trying in SQL view is: SELECT UserLogin, COUNT(*) AS NumofFails
FROM tblQA
WHERE NoteDate between 6/1/17 and 6/30/17 AND Pass=0
Group by UserLogin but I'm getting no results back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your query "q3Red" is deriving the initial list, but you can just treat it like a table to get you started:-

Here's the sample data I used (from your q3Red, except that I have shortened the names):-

```
NoteDate    Pass    UserLogin
14/06/2017  No  st
26/06/2017  No  st
07/06/2017  No  td
27/06/2017  No  td
15/06/2017  No  td
06/06/2017  No  td
26/06/2017  No  tr
13/06/2017  No  va
23/06/2017  No  we
14/06/2017  No  we
12/06/2017  No  we
14/06/2017  No  wi
05/06/2017  No  yj
19/06/2017  No  st
```

And here's a sample query:-

```
select userlogin from q3Red group by userlogin having count (*) >=3
```

Which gives this result:-

```
userlogin
st
td
we
```

You can just wrap the SQL for your query inside parentheses in place of "q3Red" for the same effect...

Comment: Noticed that I typed the data in a different order to your screenshot, but the effect is the same...